# How to implement a lock on data currently being viewed by a user

Tags: java, jsf, icefaces

Morning gurus,

I am trying to implement a solution for allowing only one user of our web app be able to see the data they are interested in until they move away from the page.

So when a user clicks on the page they are presented with all the routes they have permission to see and no one else who has permission to see them is currently looking at.

I have partially implemented this by making an Application Scoped bean which stores a map of the routes being viewed by users keyed on their session id.

The Application Scoped bean is updated when the page's backing bean gets the routes from the database.
I have written a Filter which removes the viewed routes from the Application Scoped bean when the user leaves the page.

This all works fine :-)

But if the user leaves the page by either closing the browser tab / closing the browser or the session expiring my clean up code is bypassed.

Does anyone have suggestions how

1. I can get my clean up code to run before the tab/browser closes/session expires.
2. I can access the sessions for all users in my application scope bean (so I can iterate over them and build the watched routes map  every time it is requested)
3. An idea of a better solution.

I'm working with JSF / Icefaces 2.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

First, and most importantly, you need to decide on the acceptable delay between a user closing the browser and releasing the locks on the held objects.

If you can handle having locks persist until the session is destroyed, add an `HttpSessionListener` and perform cleanup when the session is destroyed.

If you can handle delays in the 10s of seconds, add a periodic request on the web page (either via AJAX/JS, or via an invisible IFRAME that reloads a specific page from your server), and have a `Filter` that timestamps the last access from the browser in the users session or the Application Scpoed bean you already have. A separate thread wakes up every N seconds, scans for sessions with locked objects that are older than M seconds and unlocks them.

If you need immediate notification, install an onbeforeunload event handler that notifies the server. Also, you could do it with a persistent connection or WebSocket.

In any case, you will need at least one of the first two, because the third may be unreliable.

Comment: Thanks for your replies guys, I've managed to implement a HttpSessionListener to clean up when the session times out sadly we are planning on giving the session a long lifetime so this doesn't fix all my issues.  I'm not very confident about the periodic request suggestion due to lack of js knowledge (you all made this so I may have to learn how to), do any of you have links to examples of this in an icefaces 2 app as I haven't managed to find any yet.

Answer (score 0):

Use a cronjob or something which runs periodically and indentifies closed connections etc.; you can save the last action from each user and remove the lock if this times is greater than some time.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a periodic (once a minute for example) AJAX call on your page, which keeps the lock alive.